# Do large longtext necessarily slow down a database

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, blob

I have a MySQL database that is over a million rows, and has a `longtext` type data column. Most of these are fairly short, but a few dozen of these rows have more than a MB in the `longtext` column. No WHERE or LIKE statements are made on the `longtext` column. Only select statements a few rows at most at a time. It would be nice to keep this data in the database, but the database is slow. I have two tables with a million records, one is 100MB, but this one is 4GB, mostly in the `longtext` column. I'm not sure if that's a performance concern or not.

We're wondering if removing these rows would result in a performance increase for SELECT, CREATE, UPDATE commands, or if it should not have an effect.

Comment: What is th eversion of MySQL that you use, what is the engine of the tables and what is their `ROW_FORMAT`? See this page for some initial details about how InnoDB stored long columns (blob, text, long varchars): [Blob Storage in Innodb](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/) (and this is from 6 years ago, some things may have been improved since). And this one, from mysql server blog: http://mysqlserverteam.com/externally-stored-fields-in-innodb/

Comment: "Fairly short" - With InnoDB there are cutoffs at 767 bytes and 8KB.  Please provide more details about the distribution of text/blob size, plus the `ROW_FORMAT` and `ENGINE`.  With those details, we can give more details. Without the details requested, the general answers "not a problem".  (Or at least, not enough of a problem to worry about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MyISAM tables, fragmentation can easily occur where rows have variable length and deletions are frequent. This can affect index reads and full table scan performance by increasing the number of pages that need to be read to find the data, and preventing the use of sequential read-ahead technology.

See this Serverfault question for good info on fragmentation, how to detect it and react to it: https://serverfault.com/questions/202000/how-find-and-fix-fragmented-mysql-tables

This is less applicable on InnoDB, where large objects are stored separately to the rest of the rows, and tables are index-oriented.